# Show a-cursor in VR mode only

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently creating a panorama viewer in a-frame. In desktop/browser mode the mouse cursor should be the only cursor I want to see. In VR mode the gaze-based a-cursor circle should be the only cursor I want to see. Is this possible?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Check this out](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/core/scene.html#events)

Comment: Thanks, it's working! :)

Comment: Glad to hear this.... I've posted it as an answer, feel free to accept it if solved your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must check [a-frame events](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/core/scene.html#events), you will find [`enter-vr`](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/core/scene.html#events_enter_vr) and [`exit-vr`](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/core/scene.html#events_exit_vr) that is what are you searching for.